# Scratch Detection with Limited Samples

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, anomaly-detection

**Problem:**
I'm trying to build a image processing program which detects scratches on a module.
As seen in the image below, a few scratches can be found.
One of the problems is that I have only two samples with scratches.

**Question:**
What would be the best way to find the scratches under the limited number of sample condition?
(if detection is too hard, accepted / not accepted classification is also fine)

**What I tried:**
I tried to detect the scratches by using GMM(gaussian mixture model)
-> It didn't work because of too many features. GMM is only effective on object such as textures.
I will try to implement Deep Learning, but I'm not sure if it will work or not.

**Image Sample**
[image: Model with scratches]

Comment: Only 2 samples? Then you better get some more or synthesize some plausible ones. Even for validation of an unsupervised method that is not really enough. Should have min 10+10 for validation and test.

Comment: How many normal images do you have? You should probably use unsupervised anomaly detection for this, then you primarily need "normal" images. And try transfer learning from an existing pre-trained image model